# Best practice to access and display data from DB that is common across all pages

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a webstore with a bunch of Spring MVC controllers defined for each JSP page such as HomePageController, CategoryPageController, ProductPageController, CartPageController etc. and all these controllers makes a call to the DB to fetch and display the menu on top of JSP pages. Each of the controllers mentioned above makes a call to the DB in order to fetch the menu.

I am using Spring 3.0 framework.

**HomePageController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(HOME_PAGE_CONTROLLER)
public class HomePageController extends BasePageController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("menuCategories", masterDataService.getAllMenuCategories());
        return showPage(mav, HOME_PAGE_URL);
    }
}
```

I kind of feel that this call is redundant because 
1) all the controllers are making this call to build the menu 
2) difficult to maintain because change in business logic will require changes in multiple controllers

What is the best practice in this type of scenario? How can I avoid this call getting make from multiple controllers? Is there a way to make this call at a central location so that this piece of code does not cut across all the controllers?

Comment: Use @ControllerAdvice or extend HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Avoid duplicating code across controller classes* - If all controller classes extend `BasePageController`:

```
public abstract class BasePageController {
  ...

  @ModelAttribute
  public void initMenuCategories(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("menuCategories", masterDataService.getAllMenuCategories());
  }

  ...
}
```

*Reduce database calls per page* - Consider caching the menu categories if they don't change too often:

```
@Service
public class MasterDataService {
   ...

   @Cacheable(key = "menu", value = "menu")
   public List<MenuCategory> getAllMenuCategories() { ... }

   ...
}
```

You will have to add a cache named `menu` to your service layer configuration for this to work.  See the documentation on [Caching with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) for details.